# Hibernate Prepares Statements each time

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

i'm working at a DB intensive System with Spring, Hibernate\JPA and MsSQlServer (PROD) and H2Db( DEV).

I got some time- intensive calls, which make a lot of queries too.
Enabling the Hibernate Statistics in my DEV environment I've see that hibernate seems to prepare the statements each time a query is performed. Below the Hibernate report for the DEV environment (which is not so terrible, but in PROD with a concurrent environment it degrades quite a lot)

> ```
>  695050 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
>
> 46807 nanoseconds spent releasing 1 JDBC connections;
>
> **1009874 nanoseconds spent preparing 3 JDBC statements;**
>
> 351373 nanoseconds spent executing 3 JDBC statements;
>
> 0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
>
> 0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
>
> 0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
>
> 0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
>
> 21867159 nanoseconds spent executing 1 flushes (flushing a total of 440 entities and 16 collections);
>
> 9618 nanoseconds spent executing 1 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
> ```

Is there a way to let Hibernate reuse PreparedStatements ?

Comment: Use a connection pool library that supports prepared statement caching.

Comment: We take the datasource from the AS (JBOSS EAP 6.4) and delegate to it the connection pooling, how should we ? Do  you have some lib example ?